# Disable Scrolling Up After Point on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to disable the ability to scroll up on an html page once I get beyond a certain point. I also need a mechanism for returning to the top of said page.

I've tried to accomplish this with the following code, but it hasn't worked for me yet because the page is responsive (thus the point's location may change with the window's size).

```
$(function() {
    var scrollPoint = 200;
    var scrolledPast = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint ? scrolledPast = true : '';
        $(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint && scrolledPast == true ?     
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint) : '';
    }).scroll();
});
```

Can this be accomplished with Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: Update: I need the point where start the "disabele scroll up" us after a screen from the top of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var minScroll = 200;
var scrollPoint = 0;

function setPage(id) {
  scrollPoint = $("#" + id).offset().top;
  document.location.href = "#" + id;
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var current = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPoint >= minScroll) {
      if (current < scrollPoint) $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint);
      else {
        //scrollPoint = $(window).scrollTop();
      }
    } else {
      //scrollPoint = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
  });

  $("#return").on("click", function() {
    scrollPoint = 0;
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });

  wave("page1");
  wave("page2");
  wave("page3");
});

function wave(id) {
  var maxWave = 30;
  var minWave = 2;

  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var waveSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxWave - minWave) + minWave);
    var j = 0;

    for (j; j < waveSize; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        $("#" + id).append("#");
      }
      console.log(j + " vs " + waveSize);
      if (j == waveSize - 1) $("#" + id).append(")");
      else $("#" + id).append("\\");

      $("#" + id).append("<br />");
    }

    for (j = j - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
      for (var k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        $("#" + id).append("#");
      }
      $("#" + id).append("/<br />");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#return {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  right: 5px;
}
#pg1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  right: 5px;
}
#pg2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 95px;
  right: 5px;
}
#pg3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 115px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="return">Return To Top</button>
<button id="pg1" onclick="setPage('page1');">Page 1</button>
<button id="pg2" onclick="setPage('page2');">Page 2</button>
<button id="pg3" onclick="setPage('page3');">Page 3</button>

<div id="page1">Page 1
  <br />
</div>
<div id="page2">Page 2
  <br />
</div>
<div id="page3">Page 3
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this initially work, but it doesn't allow me to return to the start point, I want to be able to scroll up to the start point. Thank you

Comment: At what point do you want to be able to scroll up? Because your logic that you just said is that you want to disable scrolling up... But you need to be able to scroll up.

Comment: @vlk Added a button to demonstrate how you can return to top.

Comment: Yes with the button it works, but i need to be able to return simply scrolling. When the page is open it start from an anchorpoint. I need to disable the ability to scroll up from this point to the top.

Comment: @vlk Added the paging as you asked. I won't be making any more changes though. You should be able to look at the code and figure out what you want to do.

Comment: Care to explain what you're doing here? While this may answer the question it would be better to include some context explaining how it works.